# Switch the sass class based on javascript condition

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, sass

I have a web portal for two different countries. Each country has different UX(small css changes like padding, color, font) design. There are more countries in line.

I would like to say the country name via javascript and then based on the value passed from javascript then the Sass (SCSS classes) should behave . Basically i would like to play with SASS variable file based on the country name.

is it possible and can you give me some idea ?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Add a CSS class for each country and use those in selectors.

Comment: Huh? Read [ask] and create a [mcve]

Comment: @SLaks , do you mean ng-class in html? i am going to have more countries

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to play with SASS variables based on JS. SASS compiles to CSS first, and therefore cannot be affected by JS.

What you can do, is create a set of CSS classes for the body or some high-level div, that will affect some elements of the nested css.

Here's a generic example, as I have no idea what your CSS looks like:

```
body {
  font-family: "Arial";
  color: black;
  table { border-color: red; }

  &.germany {
     color: red;
     table {border-color: yellow;}

  }
  &.namibia {
     color: green;
     table {border-color: pink;}

  }

}
```

In this case, I would ask JS to add the class `germany` or `namibia` to the HTML `body`, and the corresponding styles would be applied.